# Command Button that runs (click) on another button in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet 4(Name 1) has a button, this button will take the user to another Sheet with a graph Sheet3(Graph)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph").Activate
End Sub
```

Goal: Have the button in Sheet 4(Name 1) to also click on another button in another sheet1(Basic) this will result with updating the graph.

I understand that it may sound easier to just have the button to also excute the code but not in this case.

Comment: *...but not in this case.*. **why** not? This seems like an obvious candidate for some code-refactoring. Abstract the "updating" code into a standalone procedure that can be called from whatever button/event/etc required.

Comment: @DavidZemens I think OP meant copy-pasta'ing the code over to that other button - which I agree is a bad idea.

Comment: Side note: find the `Graph` sheet in the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), then change its `(Name)` property to e.g. `GraphSheet`. Now you can do `GraphSheet.Activate` - there's never a need to fetch any sheet from `ThisWorkbook` if the sheet exists at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

The "other button" probably looks something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton42_Click()
    'do stuff...
End Sub
```

Change it to this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton42_Click()
    DoStuff
End Sub
```

Put the `DoStuff` procedure in a standard module (note the `Public` access modifier):

```
Public Sub DoStuff()
    'do stuff...
End Sub
```

If you don't want `DoStuff` to be visibly exposed as a macro, add `Option Private Module` at the top, near where you put `Option Explicit` :)

And then your button can do this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    DoStuff
End Sub
```

Don't invoke `Click` handlers from user code - event handlers are meant to be `Private` and invoked by event provider objects.